# Custom cue points on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a cue points implementation on a vzaar's video.

[DEMO](http://cryptic-earth-5001.herokuapp.com/quiz/vzaar/)

[CODE](https://github.com/Verurteilt/quiz_videos_heroku/blob/master/quiz/templates/vzaar.html)

If you play the video, on the second 3 and 9 a `div` will appear over the video asking something, if you answer fine the video keeps going until finishing. If you play the video again, the answers will be asked again and so on.

Basically what my code does is:

1. Takes an object key-value (I will call it `cuepointsobject` from now on) where the key is the second and the value
   the id of the div that will appear over the video.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var myPlayer = document.getElementById('video_movie');
        var video2 = $(myPlayer);
        window.tiempos_questions_originales = video2.data('times');
        window.tiempos_falsos = $.extend({}, tiempos_questions_originales);
        myPlayer = new vzPlayer('video_movie');
        myPlayer.ready(function(){
            checar_tiempos(myPlayer,cb,tiempos_falsos);
        });        
   });
   ```
2. Then asks for the current time of the video to the vzaar's api,the code parses the second into an integer, if the second parsed is on the object the div shows up.

   ```
   function checar_tiempos(player,cb,tiempos){
      var tiempo;
      player.getTime(function(time){
         tiempo = time; //Current Time of the video playing
         var new_tiempos = cb(parseInt(tiempo),tiempos,player); //Gets the "new times" if a question has been answered the "new times" is the cuepointsobject without the answered question so that question won't be asked again until the video finishes (when the cuepointsobject is set as the beginning)
        setTimeout(function(){ checar_tiempos(player,cb,new_tiempos) }, 300); //Every 3 miliseconds this function will be executed again.
      });
   }

   function cb(time,tiempos,player){
        var _video = player;
       player.addEventListener('playState', function(i){
            player.ended = i; //Sets the state of the video (buffering, mediaPlaying,mediaEnded)
       });
       if(player.ended == "mediaEnded"){
          tiempos = $.extend({}, tiempos_questions_originales); //If the video has finished the cuepointsobject is set again as the beginning of the video.
       }
       if(String(time) in tiempos){ //The current time is inside cuepointsobject
           var question = tiempos[String(time)];
           delete tiempos[String(time)]; //Delete the question from the cuepointsobject so it won't be asked again during the video, until finishing.
          if($(question).is(":visible") == false){
             _video.pause(); //Pause the video
             $(question).show(); //The question appears
          }
       }
       return tiempos; //Returns the "new times"
   }
   ```

So far all good, the problem I have is:

> When you are watching the video,let's gonna
>   suppose you ask the question on the second 3 then on the second 10 you
>   wanna return and ask the question on the second 3 again, but if you
>   put the video on the second 3 (the video hasn't finished yet), the div
>   won't show up, so my question is: How would you do it so that the
>   question appears again?

Any doubt please let me know. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already reset the questions when the media ends by looking for that event `playState`.  You can do the same thing when the user starts the video at a different spot, by looking for the `seekbar` interaction.  Make the following code modification, I just added one additional `addEventListener` and one more case to the `if` statement that follows:

```
player.addEventListener('playState', function(i){
     player.ended = i; //Sets the state of the video (buffering, mediaPlaying,mediaEnded)
});
player.addEventListener('interaction', function(type) {
     player.interaction = type; //Sets the type of user interaction (seekbar, etc)
});
if(player.ended == "mediaEnded" || player.interaction == "seekbar"){
```

Comment: I have to wait 24 hours to give you the bounty, you'll get it tomorrow :D